# ASUS GL552 strange behavior

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply

I'm owner of an ASUS ROG GL552JX. I got some strange behavior , I'll list them all :

1. Starting the computer after shutting it down will result in a frozen ASUS logo at the boot time.To resolve this I just need to restart it once and then everything is okay.
2. If the power supply is connected to the socket but not connected to the laptop it will make some ticking sound like "TIK TIK TIK TIK" ; and if I connected the power supply to the laptop while it is shutdown it will make a strange sound like "FZZ FZZ FZZ" , but when I starts the laptop the sound disappears and everything works perfectly ! (All the sounds are coming from the power supply not the laptop)

Comment: What makes the sound the laptop or the charger?  Be specific update your question

Comment: I am sorry , the sounds are coming from the power supply.

Comment: Sounds like the power supply should be replaced